# Yet another one on "deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations)"

Tags: nhibernate

Most all of the references to this NHibernate error (in the title) talk about child objects being deleted while still contained in a parent collection that would only re-save them later negating their "delete" (which is what the error states and the suggestion to remove object from associations that are re-saving it).

But in my case, the error happens while deleting the parent record (then the "child" is deleted via the association, so I **don't want** the association removed, as the error suggest)

It would have made sense if that happened every time, but I only observe this error <strike>intermittently</strike>, running exactly the same code but only against particular records. Other identical records don't trigger the condition and the delete goes through (all the time I deal with one `Customer` with two `address`-es.)

Not sure how much and what code to show. This is my "parent" object mapping:

I've got a OneCustomer-to-ManyAddresses relation mapped as a "set" of CustomerAddress "composite elements"

```
<class name="Customer" table="Customer">
        <id name="Id" column="[Id]" type="Guid">
            <generator class="guid" />
        </id>
        ...
        <set name="AddressList" lazy="true" table="CustomerAddress" cascade="all-delete-orphan" >
            <key column="[CustomerId]"/>
            <composite-element class="CustomerAddress">
                <parent name="Customer"/>
                <many-to-one name="Address"
                class="Address"
                column="[AddressId]"
                not-null="true"
                cascade="all"/>
                ...
            </composite-element>
        </set>
```

And this is the mapping for the "composite" object `CustomerAddress`:

```
<class name="CustomerAddress" table="CustomerAddress" >
        <id name="Id" column="[Id]" type="Guid">
            <generator class="guid" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one
            name="Address"
            column="[AddressId]"
            class="Address"
            not-null="true"
            cascade="all"/>

        <many-to-one
            name="Customer"
            column="[CustomerId]"
            class="Customer"
            not-null="true"
            cascade="all"/>
            ...
    </class>
```

What is the explanation of the error and its intermittent nature?

**ADDITIONAL INFO**

After further examination - looking for another collection that may hold a reference to same "Address" child, I saw the following mapping:

```
<class name="Address" table="Address">
        <id name="Id" column="[id]" type="Guid" >
            <generator class="guid" />
        </id>

        <!-- REMOVING THE FOLLOWING <BAG> SEEMS TO BE FIXING MY ISSUE -->
        <bag name="CustomerAddressList" inverse="true" cascade="none" lazy="false" >
            <key>
                <column name="[AddressId]" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="CustomerAddress" />
        </bag>

    </class>
```

Removing the `<bag name="CustomerAddressList"...` seems to fix my issue. Explanation?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to have a guess:

You have a bi-directional association, but you haven't specified that one of them is the non-owner (by setting "inverse = true").

Try modifying the CustomerAddress relationship as follows:

```
<class name="CustomerAddress" table="CustomerAddress" >
    <id name="Id" column="[Id]" type="Guid">
        <generator class="guid" />
    </id>
    <many-to-one
        name="Address"
        column="[AddressId]"
        class="Address"
        not-null="true"
        cascade="all"/>

    <many-to-one
        name="Customer"
        column="[CustomerId]"
        class="Customer"
        not-null="true"
        cascade="all"
        inverse="true"
         />
        ...
</class>
```

Comment: Thanks. This sounds plausible. Something else seems to have fixed my issue - along the lines of your answer, but different - please see my edit to original question.

Answer (score 0):

why do you have two mappings for CustomerAddress table (one as composite Element and one as Entity)? remove the entity mapping for Customer address and it should work.

Comment: Because I sometimes work with CustomerAddress classes on their own - I thought I need the stand-alone mapping. Thanks for looking into this. I'll try